# Some Xcode custom key bindings don't work

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, xcode9

why do some Xcode custom created keybindings work but others don't. I've created a custom action in IDETextKeyBindingSet.plist to insert a blank line above the current line of code. up until Xcode 8 it worked fine and i bound it to key combination <kbd>Ctrl + Opn + Cmd + i</kbd>. now in Xcode11 i can't bind this custom action to the same key combination set ... somehow it seems to run the profile command (<kbd>Cmd + i</kbd>) even though I've bound it to Ctrl+Opn+Cmd+i (and the keybindings area says <kbd>Ctrl + Opn + Cmd + i</kbd> is available and not bound to anything else at the point of customisation) ... nor can I bind it to <kbd>Ctrl + Opn + Cmd + =</kbd> (again thats an unused combination) .... but it works if i bind it to <kbd>Ctrl + Opn + Cmd + a</kbd>  ... i have about 6 timesaving keyboard shortcuts (i.e. delete entire line, insert line above and tab to beginning of line, etc) and its frustrating that i have to change the relevant keys i bind them too each time a new Xcode comes out.

Comment: Why does it seem that you always have to fight Xcode to make it work?  Come on Apple!